# Google barchart tooltip no tail

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Im using google barchart and I added tooltips with html in it. The problem is that the tooltip does not have the tail arrow thing. I saw that some charts has the arrow while others dont?

function drawFrequencyCharts(response) {

```
var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data2.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data2.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data2.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
```

> .... some code

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data2);


var chart2 = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));

var options2 = {
    height: 300,
    width: 500,
    series: {
        0: {
            type: 'bars'
        },
        1: {
            type: 'line',
            color: 'grey',
            lineWidth: 0,
            pointSize: 0,
            visibleInLegend: false
        }
    },
    colors: ['#3394D1'],
    backgroundColor: {
        fill: 'transparent'
    },
    legend: 'none',
    vAxis: {
        maxValue: 100,
        minValue: 0,
        ticks: [{
            v: 0,
            f: '0%'
        }, {
            v: 25,
            f: '25%'
        }, {
            v: 50,
            f: '50%'
        }, {
            v: 75,
            f: '75%'
        }, {
            v: 100,
            f: '100%'
        }, ]
    },
    hAxis: {
        format: '#',
        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
            min: 0.1
        },
        title: 'Drops per day',
        gridlines: {
            color: 'transparent'
        },
        ticks: ticksValues
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        startup: chartAnimate
    }
};


chart2.draw(view, options2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the "tail" is that you're using `tooltip:{isHtml:true}`. They are not shown with the tip, just an ordinary "box" floating above your chart.

If you revoke to "normal" tooltip, then you'll see the 'tail'.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/u3fuxruz/) where you can see the difference.

Comment: Is there any way to have both the tail and customizable HTML inside tooltips?